# Address Already in Use: Bind Exception

Tags: opc, opc-ua

I'm using the open source OPC UA client/server implementation of Eclipse Milo. I got a S7-1500 Siemens PLC configurated with a IP address, Port number and Urn name.

To test the Milo Client **ReadExample** I changed the server configuration settings so that instead of making it's own default server it would connect to the Siemens PLC.

I did but instead of seeing and reading from the PLC it gives an exception.

[image: Exception]

[image: Changes]

[image: Changes2]

Comment: restart your pc and try again

Comment: I tried but it gave the same exception.

Thanks for your reaction

Comment: You only want to construct the OpcUaClient. Don't build the OpcUaServerConfig and don't construct the OpcUaServer.

Comment: Andrew you helped me to fix it. John Joe and andrewcullen thanks for the help! I'll post the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The **ReadExample** is running through the **ClientExampleRunner** where the configuration of the server is called. I first cleaned the project and after that I only runned the **ReadExample**

[image: ClientExampleRunner]

Only now after some instruction I commented the calls to the **ExampleServer**, where the configuration is made, out and changed the endpoint to the address of the PLC.

[image]

Don't forget to comment out the exampleServer.shutdown().get() at the end because it will give you an error.

[image]